# Menu flicker when hover

Tags: html, css

I tired to fixed it from last 6 days.but i cant find the solution. Click on below link and check out courses and about menu

http://stalwartstutorials.com/

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    /* border: 1px solid transparent; */
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So we have to watch and read tutorials you did and then match your css to something you have seen on that website?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of padding issue

CSS

```
 .yamm .nav > li > a
{
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

add this code to your css

Hope this helps..